# Prove that $E(a) = E(b)$ for $a,b \in V$ iff $a - b$ is in a subspace of V

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification, vector-fields

Let $H$ be a subspace of $V$.

For $c \in V$, define $E(c) = \{c + h\,|\,h\in H\}$.

Show that for $a,b \in V, E(a) = E(b)$ iff $a - b\in H$.

My attempt:
\begin{align*}
E(a) &= \{a + h\,|\,h\in H\}\\
E(b) &= \{b + h\,|\,h\in H\}
\end{align*}
Since $a - b \in H$,
\begin{align*}
E(a) &= \{a + (a-b)\,|\,a-b\in H\}\\
&=\{2a - b\,|\,a-b\in H\}\\\\
E(b) &= \{b + (a-b)\,|\,a-b\in H\}\\
&= \{a\,|\,a-b\in H\}
\end{align*}

Which does not show that $E(a) = E(b)$. How is it done?

Answer (score 1):

I denote , commonly, $E(a)$ as $a+H$. So your question is : to prove $a+H=b+H \iff a-b \in H$

$\implies$: Assume $a+H=b+H$.

Now $$a=a+0 \in a+H=b+H$$ so that $a=b+h$ where $h \in H$. Thus, $a-b=h \in H$

$\impliedby:$ Assume $a-b \in H$

Let $k \in a+H$. Then $k=a+h$ where $h \in H$.

Now, $$k=a+h=b+\color{red}{(a-b)+h} \in b+H$$

Thus, $a+H \subseteq b+H$. Similarly prove other inclusion

Comment: I wish to clarify, where did you get $a+H$?

Comment: Most undergraduate texts denote/define  $a+H:=\{a+h : h \in H\}$ for the coset $a+H$. By your notation, this set is $E(a)$

Comment: Can you denote it based from the problem? I'm having a difficulty understanding $a = a + 0 \in a + H = b + H$.