# Prove $E(a) = E(b)$ if $a, b \in V$ and $E(a) \cap E(b) \neq \varnothing$

Tags: vector-spaces, vector-fields

This is a continuation of my previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4157764/prove-that-ea-eb-for-a-b-in-v-iff-a-b-is-in-a-subspace-of-v/4157777?noredirect=1#comment8609988_4157777).

For $c \in V$, define $E(c) = \{c + h\,|\,h\in H\}$.

Prove that if $a, b \in V$ and $E(a) \cap E(b) \neq \varnothing$, then $E(a) = E(b)$.

My initial attempt:

Suppose $E(a) \cap E(b) \neq \varnothing$ and let $u \in E(a) \cap E(b)$. Then there are $\alpha, \beta \in H$ such that $u = a+\alpha = b + \beta$. Since $H$ is a subspace of $V$ and $\alpha,\beta \in H\rightarrow (\alpha-\beta) \in H$ and $$a-b=\beta-\alpha\in H$$

Let $a_1 \in E(a)$, $a_1 = v + a$. Observe:
\begin{align*}
        a_1 = v - (a + b) + (a - b) + a= (v - (a - b)) + b
    \end{align*}
Since $v - (a + b) \in H$, it follows that $a_1 \in E(b)$.
Now, we show the other implication:

Let $b_1 \in E(b)$, $b_1 = v + b$. Observe:
\begin{align*}
        b_1 = v - (b + a) + (b - a) + b= (v + (b - a)) + a
    \end{align*}
Since $v - (b + a) \in H$, it follows that $b_1 \in E(a)$. Thus, $E(a) = E(b)$ for $E(a)\cap E(b) \neq \varnothing$.

Comment: Did you mean to write $\neq$?

Comment: The title had a typo. It's supposed to be $\neq$.

Comment: To prove $P\Rightarrow Q$, you assume $P$.

Comment: Hint : Consider two parallel lines in the planes. Either they coincide, or there are disjoint.

Comment: Please check my attempt.

Comment: There are some typos, like "Then there are $a,b\in H$", I assume you mean $\alpha,\beta\in H$.  The part about $v_1$ is basically correct, if you change $\alpha,\beta$ with $a,b$, so write $$v_1=a+v=b+v+(a-b)$$ and $v+(a-b)\in H$. Also, you have proved that $E(a)\subseteq E(b)$, you need the other implication (which is immediate, just exchange $a,b$ and you get $E(b)\subseteq E(a)$)

Comment: I added in a proof for the other implication. Is it accurate?

Comment: Basically yes (since $a-b\in H$, then also $b-a=-(a-b)\in H$), the line in the middle should be $$v+b=v+(b-a)+a$$

Comment: Updated. Like that?